# get object for all my documents in Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I want to send a JSON of all my docuements in Firestore from my backend created with express

The Firestore docs says how to get all documents but the method is with `forEach` and express can send only once the response. So the problem is that I don't know how to render all forEach in a variable to send once for the headers

This is the code of Firestore docs:

```
  db.collection('users').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You could for example create and populate a JavaScript object of type [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
  db.collection('users').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      var usersArray = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        usersArray.push(doc.data());
      });
      //do something with the usersArray
      //e.g. return usersArray;
      ///or return JSON.stringify(usersArray)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```