# Iterating over firestore docs - getting a promise

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am pulling down some docs from a firestore collection and trying to store the results in an array. For some reason, what is being returned below is a promise. How do I get the array?

Component - designList is a promise

```
    this.designList = this.FirebaseService.getDocsByUserId('designs', 'designerId')
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        var designList = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            designList.push(doc.data());
        });
        return designList;
    })
```

Service making the call

```
getDocsByUserId( collection, getParam ) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    var docRef = this.afs.collection(collection, ref => ref.where(getParam, '==', user.uid));
    return docRef.ref.get();
}
```

Comment: The caller will also have to use `then`.  This is going to be required since `get()` also returns a promise.  It's not possible to covert an async function to a sync function.

Comment: I don't understand. The get function returns a promise. Doesn't the use of the ".then" in the component resolve the promise?

Comment: No, then just returns another promise that resolves when its work is complete. That's how you are able to chain work with a series of thens. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: But the code within the .then is carried out once the promise resolves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get object for all my documents in Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322010/get-object-for-all-my-documents-in-cloud-firestore)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `async/await`.

```
async populateDesignList() {
  this.designList = [];
  const querySnapShot = await this.FirebaseService.getDocsByUserId('designs', 'designerId');

  querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.data());
     this.designList.push(doc.data());
  });
}
```